# How do I resolve dplyr::mutate error "Unexpected '='"?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, mutate

I'm having issues with dplyr::mutate(). It works fine when I use it regularly, but it throws an error when I use it in a function and then try to define that function.

My goal is to create a function that lets you calculate the quartiles of a distribution for a whole data set, as well as for grouped subsets of that data set.

For example:

This works fine

```html
dat <- mtcars

test_table <- dat %>%
  bind_rows(mutate(., cyl = "all")) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(mpg_q25 = quantile(mpg, prob = .25),
            mpg_q50 = quantile(mpg, prob = .50),
            mpg_q75 = quantile(mpg, prob = .75),
            count = n())

test_table
```

Output

```html
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  cyl   mpg_q25 mpg_q50 mpg_q75 count
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
1 4        22.8    26      30.4    11
2 6        18.6    19.7    21       7
3 8        14.4    15.2    16.2    14
4 all      15.4    19.2    22.8    32
```

However, this does not

```html
mpg_table <- function(df, grouping_var, val) {
  bind_rows(mutate(., {{grouping_var}} = "all")) %>%
    group_by({{grouping_var}}) %>%
    summarise(mpgq25 = quantile({{mpg}}, prob = .25),
              mpgq50 = quantile({{mpg}}, prob = .50),
              mpgq75 = quantile({{mpg}}, prob = .75),
              count = n())
}

mpg_table(dat, cyl, mpg)
```

Output from trying to define the function

```html
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"mpg_table <- function(df, grouping_var, val) {
  bind_rows(mutate(., {{grouping_var}} ="
```

Anyone have any idea what's going wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
data(mtcars)
dat <- mtcars
mpg_table <- function(df, grouping_var, val) {
  df %>% 
    mutate({{grouping_var}} := as.character({{grouping_var}})) %>% 
    bind_rows(mutate(., {{grouping_var}} := "all")) %>%
    group_by({{grouping_var}}) %>%
    summarise("{{val}}q25" := quantile({{val}}, prob = .25),
              "{{val}}q50" := quantile({{val}}, prob = .50),
              "{{val}}q75" := quantile({{val}}, prob = .75),
              count = n())
}

mpg_table(dat, cyl, mpg)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   cyl   mpgq25 mpgq50 mpgq75 count
#>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
#> 1 4       22.8   26     30.4    11
#> 2 6       18.6   19.7   21       7
#> 3 8       14.4   15.2   16.2    14
#> 4 all     15.4   19.2   22.8    32
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The `:=` allows you to pass a variable in as the name of a new variable to be created. I also used the same construct for the variable names for the quantiles.  This means that if you pass `drat` as `val` for example, you would get `dratq25`, `dratq50` and `dratq75` as the variables in the output.

The other problem you run into is a format problem.  The `cyl` variable is numeric and you're trying to bind it to a data frame whose `cyl` variable is a character.  The first step in the code above changes the `grouping_var` to character to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working! I solved the mismatch in data type for this post by `dat$cyl = as.character(dat$cyl)` (which I didn't include in the example). But your solution seems to be better suited for a variety of data sets.